# Icons not comming in bar menu android

Tags: android

unable to put icons in  Action bar menu list.

here is my menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ihbpro"
    android:title="one"
    >

<item
    android:id="@+id/Home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/ihbprom"
    android:title="IHB"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ihbpro"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/Account"
    android:title="Account"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
   />


</item>
</menu>
```

Currently,

it's like this:

- one
- Home
- IHB
- Account

But I want it like:

- [icon]one
- [icon]Home
- [icon]IHB
- [icon]Account

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
      {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu);
          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
  ```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

use  `app:showAsAction="always"` in your `<item>` tag

Your `menu.xml` will be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_ihbpro"
        android:title="one">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Home"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/ihbprom"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_ihbpro"
            android:title="IHB"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Account"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
            android:title="Account"
            app:showAsAction="always" />


    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: app:showAsAction="always" creates icon on navigation bar. But I need icon on menu droplist